# Tkinter: Tracing the state of a widget

Tags: python, tkinter, python-3.4

I am aware that it is possible to trace the changes of, say, the entered value in an Entry widget by using e.g. a StringVar and a variable observer like Trace. Is it possible to also trace the state of a widget? Let's say we have the code:

```
from tkinter import *

class My_Window:

    def __init__(self, root):

        self.button1 = Button(root, text="Enter", command = self.disable_entrybox)
        self.get_info_box1 = Entry(root)
        self.button2 = Button(root, text="Enter", command = self.disable_entrybox) 
        self.get_info_box2 = Entry(root)
        self.button1.pack()
        self.get_info_box1.pack()
        self.button2.pack()
        self.get_info_box2.pack()
        self.get_info_box2.config(state="disable")

    def disable_entrybox(self):
        x = self.get_info_box1.get()
        self.get_info_box1.config(state="disable")


root = Tk()
my_window = My_Window(root)
root.mainloop()
```

And I want to trace if `get_info_box1`is disabled or not, and if it's disabled, change the state of `get_info_box2` to "normal". Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Since you're manually enabling/disabling `get_info_box1` yourself, why not disable/enable `get_info_box2` while you're at it? If you want, you can make a function that disables all of the program's `Entry` widgets and then enables the one that was passed to it.

Comment: That would certainly work in this case, however I only wrote this code to clarify my question. In the script I'm currently trying to write my second Entry widget must remain disabled until the user has written something into the first Entry widget. Just like in this code I've made it so the Entry widget will be disabled after the info has been received, I therefore thought if I could keep track of when my first widget had changed its state I could make sure the second one was activated at the right moment. 
I think your second suggestion might do the trick, I'll give it a shot! Thank you!

Comment: It sounds like you need to [trace the `StringVar`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/variable.htm). In the callback function, you can check the state of those `StringVar`s (or just `self.get_info_box1234.get()`) and then enable/disable the various widgets as necessary.

Comment: Are you wanting to _trace_ state changes, or simply query the existing state?

Comment: For now I got around the problem through some hard coding making the first button press also call another funciton activating the second box, I will try your suggestion to see if I can make it work out in a better way!
I think it's the state changes I want to trace, the entry boxes are only supposed to be open for entry once per script run, after the info's been registered the will be disabled for the rest of the program run time.